# Dynamic IP on VPN and Zabbix

Tags: vpn, zabbix

I have an L2TP VPN on a Zyxel USG310, I'd like to monitor every client on it with zabbix, I tried to set static IP on the client to make it possible, but I discovered that, unfortunately, it's impossible ( http://kb.zyxel.com/KB/searchArticle!gwsViewDetail.action?articleOid=015381&lang=EN ). Is it possible to dynamically "adapt" zabbix data with the zabbix hostname setted in the configuration of the agent?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your agents can connect to the Zabbix server, use active items. In that case agent asks the server for a list of items to monitor, then sends in the data. Agents are identified by host name - that is controlled by the Hostname* parameters in the agent configuration file. On the server side, "Host name" field is used (not DNS, not IP, not visible name...). Note that host names are case sensitive. By default agent connects to the server on port 10051.

Comment: Hi, could you be more detailed? trying to set just hostname gives me Field "Agent or SNMP or JMX or IPMI interface" is mandatory." and setting it without IP gives similar result, I'm a beginner with zabbix, sorry if I don't understand you correctly

Comment: The agent interface is only used for passive items. If you do not create any passive items, the interface is ignored. Do not remove it :)

Comment: I activated autoregistration on a few clients on the VPN, it seems work, I hope tomorrow they will update correctly! Thank you!

Comment: As the question about creating a host without any interfaces comes up often, here's also a bit longer explanation :) http://www.zabbixbook.com/2016/11/22/can-i-have-a-host-without-interfaces/